# How is Loki alive in the second movie of Thor?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor

Loki let goes of Thor and float into space and dies in the first movie. Then Loki is alive in the second movie. How is this possible?

Comment: Space wouldn't necessarily kill him, he is a frost giant/ extraterrestrial being.  Peter Quill survives it with just a mask and with Loki knowledge of magic, he would know how to survive. He did sneak to the ice planet without Heimdal seeing him. In Thor Ragnarok his is forced out of the biofrost and safely arrives on Scart. He comes to Earth in Avengers through the doorway, a little worse for wear but uninjured. Thor then captures him and returns with him to Asgard where is imprisoned and remains until Thor 2.